# Maximizing the distribution of random variable

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ has binomial distribution $B(n,p)$. For what values of $j$ is $P(X = j)$ the greatest?

I know $$ P(X = j) = \frac{ n!}{(n-j)!j!} p^j(1-p)^j$$

IT seems that taking $\frac{d}{dj}$of $P(X=j)$ will be cumbersome. IS there a better way to solve this problem. Maybe by using an inequality?

Comment: It looks reasonable that the mode will be close to the mean, $np$.

Comment: It is well known that the median is at most $\sigma$ apart from the mean (by the Chebyshev-Cantelli inequality), maybe something similar holds for the mode of a smooth, square-integrable distribution.

Comment: A standard way to compute the maximum $P(X=j)$ is take the ratio of  $P(X=j+1)$ and $P(X=j)$. You will find that the ratio is always above 1 when $j$ less than $np-1$ and less than 1 when  $j$ larger than $np+1$. So you could deduce that $np$ or $np+1$ could be the desired $j$. You need to be careful in doing the ratio and determine whether it is $np$ or $np+1$ or both.